# CSS - Is it possible to center (horizontaly) an absolute element that is bigger than it's parent without using negative values?

Tags: css, center, absolute

So I know there are multiple ways to center a child element. This is a purely theoretical question. I am just wondering if there are any other ways to center an element. 
I created an overview of the multiple techniques for centering elements at the bottom of this post. The problem is based on the first example.

[gif-reference of the question](https://i.gyazo.com/7dfcc6247136544495328a6867e9e6d2.mp4)

overview of the solutions already provided:

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 23vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.optie0 img {
  width: 150%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; 
}

.optie1 img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.optie2 img {
  width: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.optie3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.optie3 img {
  width: 150%;
}

.optie4 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.optie5 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 23vw;
  grid-template-columns: 23vw;
}

.optie5 img {
  width: 120%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>problem:</p>
    <figure class="optie0">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606225472150-0b700e620ef5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
        alt="flower"
      />
    </figure>
    <p>solution1:</p>
    <figure class="optie1">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606225472150-0b700e620ef5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
        alt="flower"
      />
    </figure>
    <p>solution2:</p>
    <figure class="optie2">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606273789302-5ca427ba2253?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80"
        alt="cart"
      />
    </figure>
    <p>solution3:</p>
    <figure class="optie3">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606156114499-f44bbb400363?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80"
        alt="cart"
      />
    </figure>
    <p>solution4:</p>
    <figure class="optie4">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606038188414-ab55f710a8b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
        alt="cart"
      />
    </figure>
    <p>solution5:</p>
    <figure class="optie5">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606252255805-c4fab737286b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        alt="cart"
      />
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Where it is possible to determine the width of the child element. As you can see in the video reference. The code of the first example works in all direction but only when you scale the child bigger as it's parent. It is not able to center horizontal.

PLEASE: IF there is a solution to the question, don't provide one of the other solution already in my example. I understand how it works. I like the first solution and it works great in all directions except for going left if the child is bigger than it's parent.

Comment: Just to clarify: if no interactions needed with the image - can `object-fit` do the trick? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: I think object-fit is the best solution of the techniques I listed up. I guess the answer to my question is just: nope! I was just wondering this because the first one is a verry popular solution as you can see here: stackoverflow.com/a/8273750/4632878

Comment: Lol hey if you instead do `right: 50%` and `transform: translateX(50%)` - no negative values!

Comment: @MrRobboto Great answer! love it! very creative!  Maybe I should adjust my question a bit: Is it possible by starting with the code of the first example. And make it also centered when the child is bigger than it's parent.

Comment: @Luhn haha thanks, just joking - I totally get the OP. But yeah, not sure of any real answer for you unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

using 0px wide absolute parent element and `display: flex;`

```css
.parent{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid;
position: relative;
}
.container{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding:20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(100,100,100,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Your content of text or image.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The example is very similar to one of the solutions already provided. It uses a flexbox to center the child element.

Comment: It seems not very centered :3

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but I think in most cases this won't work because it requires white-space: nowrap;.

Answer (score 0):

Old-fashioned way wit transform -50%.

```
<div class="a">
  Wrapper
  <div class="b">
    Centered
  </div>  
</div>
```

```
.a { 
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 300px auto;
}

.b { 
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

[image]

Example: https://codepen.io/vovchisko/pen/BaLBGEZ

Comment: This is actually very similar to one of the solutions I already provided and does use the negative values. Which is not bad CSS at all. I am just wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: @Luhn not very similar. It not includes an additional element, and not uses flex.

Comment: @Luhn Other ways - not really. If you need to fit  - flex is the perfect fit. For some galleries with zoom features, I'd use JS to manipulate scale/position.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to center (horizontally) an absolute element that is
> bigger than its parent without using negative values?

Yes. But you don't need to use `position: absolute`.

You can straightforwardly achieve this effect by adding:

- `display:  flex`
- `justify-content: center`

to the smaller parent container.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.smaller {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height:180px;
  background-color: rgb(213, 35, 30);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.smaller::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.longer {
  z-index: 6;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: rgb(0, 24, 163);
}
```

```html
<div class="smaller">
  <div class="longer">Underground</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the container css class with this.

You'll get the required component working efficiently.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```